# How to make new columns with names from lists which are in one of existing columns in pandas, and assign values from lists from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, time

I have a problem with big dataframe *about 1kk rows, 180 columns. It starts with 3 columns. First column contains ids. Second and third contains list in each row - they are connected (first row -first element from list from 1st column is connected with first element from list from 2nd column:

```
ids | fruits | count |

1 | [grape, apple, banana]  | [7.0, 4.0, 3.0]

2 | [mango, banana, strawberry, grape] | [5.0, 8.0, 15.0, 2.0]

3 | [apple, avocado] | [9.0, 1.0]
4 | NaN | NaN
5 | [pummelo] | [12.0]
```

I want to use elements of lists from 'fruits' column, as names of new columns which will have values assigned to row and fruits. But no duplicates of columns, like that:

```
ids | grape | apple | banana | mango | strawberry | avocado | pummelo

1 | 7.0 | 4.0 | 3.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN

2 | 2.0 | NaN | 8.0 | 5.0 | 15.0 | NaN | NaN

3 | NaN | 9.0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | NaN

4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN

5 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12.0
```

Count of unique elements in set (non-duplicate sum of all lists) 'fruits'  are 180, and that is why at the end I want to have 180 columns.

The problem is speed. I tried pandas iterrows(), but when it comes to all 1kk rows that becomes neverending story. Below is the code i tried yet.

```
#making an example dataframe

import numpy as np
fruit_df = pd. DataFrame(columns=['ids','fruits','count'])
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
fruits = [['grape', 'apple', 'banana'], ['mango', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'grape'], ['apple', 'avocado'], np.nan, ['pummelo']]
count = [[7.0, 4.0, 3.0],[5.0, 8.0, 15.0, 2.0], [9.0, 1.0], np.nan, [12.0]]


#creating fruits columns in dataframe - this one timing is ok , fine for me (about 15 mins)

fruits_columns=[]
for row in fruit_df['fruits']:
    if type(row)==list:
        fruits_columns.append(row)
    else:
        fruits_columns.append(list())

import itertools
all_fruits = list(itertools.chain(*fruits_columns))

all_fruits = set(all_fruits)

for fruit in all_fruits:
    fruit_df[fruit]=np.nan


#iterating over the data - here is main problem - takes very, very long time.. works well for this tiny dataset but when it comes to 1000000 rows and 180 columns...

def iter_over_rows(data):
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if type(row['fruits'])!=float:
            for cat in range(len(row['fruits'])):       
                data[row['fruits'][cat]][index] = row['count'][cat]
```

I want to speed up this data processing thing. Thought about making dictionaries with all 180 fruits as keys and them counts as value- but at the end order will be damaged. That would be wonderful if you have any idea how to do that faster. Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do everything you want, but it will drop `ids 4` because they only contain `NA` values.

The setup is the same:

```
fruit_df = pd. DataFrame(columns=['ids','fruits','count'])
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
fruits = [['grape', 'apple', 'banana'], ['mango', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'grape'], ['apple', 'avocado'], np.nan, ['\
pummelo']]
count = [[7.0, 4.0, 3.0],[5.0, 8.0, 15.0, 2.0], [9.0, 1.0], np.nan, [12.0]]

fruit_df['ids'] = ids
fruit_df['fruits'] = fruits
fruit_df['count'] = count
```

We want to convert your rows with list to a stacked series (which basically just expands the list to new rows, while keeping the ID for the row:

```
fruit_df.set_index(['ids'], inplace=True)
fruit_series = fruit_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['fruits']), axis=1).stack()
count_series = fruit_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['count']), axis=1).stack()

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
final_df['Fruits'] = fruit_series
final_df['Counts'] = count_series
print(final_df)
```

So we see final_df looks like:

```
           Fruits  Counts
ids
1   0       grape     7.0
    1       apple     4.0
    2      banana     3.0
2   0       mango     5.0
    1      banana     8.0
    2  strawberry    15.0
    3       grape     2.0
3   0       apple     9.0
    1     avocado     1.0
5   0     pummelo    12.0
```

Okay cool, now we have our rows of list expanded to match their id, but we see this multi_index df now which we don't want so we will drop it, then pivot our table making ids the index, and fruits the columns:

```
final_df = final_df.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
final_df = final_df.pivot(index='ids', columns = 'Fruits', values = 'Counts')
print(final_df)
```

Returns:

```
Fruits  apple avocado banana grape mango pummelo strawberry
ids
1         4.0     NaN    3.0   7.0   NaN     NaN        NaN
2         NaN     NaN    8.0   2.0   5.0     NaN       15.0
3         9.0     1.0    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN
5         NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    12.0        NaN
```

Pretty close, I hope this works for you! 
The whole code combined:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fruit_df = pd. DataFrame(columns=['ids','fruits','count'])
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
fruits = [['grape', 'apple', 'banana'], ['mango', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'grape'], ['apple', 'avocado'], np.nan, ['\
pummelo']]
count = [[7.0, 4.0, 3.0],[5.0, 8.0, 15.0, 2.0], [9.0, 1.0], np.nan, [12.0]]

fruit_df['ids'] = ids
fruit_df['fruits'] = fruits
fruit_df['count'] = count


fruit_df.set_index(['ids'], inplace=True)
fruit_series = fruit_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['fruits']), axis=1).stack()
count_series = fruit_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['count']), axis=1).stack()

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

final_df['Fruits'] = fruit_series
final_df['Counts'] = count_series

final_df = final_df.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
final_df = final_df.pivot(index='ids', columns = 'Fruits', values = 'Counts')

print(final_df)
```

Comment: Worked well ! I handled NaNs with replacing just after the setup:

fruit_df['fruits'] = fruit_df['fruits'].apply(lambda d: d if isinstance(d, list) else ['no_fruit'])
fruit_df['count'] = fruit_df['count'].apply(lambda d: d if isinstance(d, list) else [-1])

And replacing them again after all (it was important for me to keep the data with nans only):

final_df = final_df.replace(to_replace=['not_fruit'], value=np.nan)
final_df = final_df.replace(to_replace=-1, value=np.nan)

Thank you for answer, I gave +1 but it seems that i'm too new here and it was counted but is not displaying

Comment: That is a good way to handle NaN's! I'm glad you found the answer to be useful and I had fun working through this.